# Android not working Turkish Characters

Tags: java, android

I use GCM between My server and Android App.
When I send new articles, If the contents Turkish,
I get null pointer exception.

This is my java code

GcmNotificationService.java

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        get_extras                  = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm    = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType          = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        crud                        = new CRUD( getApplicationContext() );

        if (!get_extras.isEmpty()) {
            if( get_extras.getString( DatabaseControl.POSTS_TITLE ) != null ){
                // Bunların tam olarak ne olduğunu anlayamadım.
                if( !GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals( messageType ) ||
                        !GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType ) ) {

                    String get_category_content  = get_extras.getString( DatabaseControl.POSTS_CONTENT );
                Log.d( "get_content", get_category_content );

                    List<CategoryHelper> new_content = new ArrayList<CategoryHelper>();
                    new_content.add(new CategoryHelper(
                            get_extras.getString( DatabaseControl.POSTS_IMAGE ),
                            get_extras.getString( DatabaseControl.POSTS_TITLE ),
                            get_extras.getString( DatabaseControl.POSTS_EXCERPT ),
                            get_extras.getString( DatabaseControl.POSTS_CONTENT ),
                            get_extras.getString( DatabaseControl.POSTS_DATE )
                    ));
                    long insert_id  =    crud.add_posts( new_content, Integer.valueOf( get_extras.getString("category_number") ), 0 );
                    if( insert_id != 0 ){
                        send_notification();
                    }
                    Log.d( "extras_detail", get_extras.toString() );
                    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my PHP code

```
//this block is to post message to GCM on-click
$pushStatus = "";
if(!empty($_GET["push"])) {
    $gcmRegID  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $pushMessage = $_POST["message"];
    if (isset($gcmRegID) && isset($pushMessage)) {
        $gcmRegIds  = array($gcmRegID);
        $today      = date("Y-m-d");
        $message = array(
            "category_image"    => "http://www.medyasef.com/wp-content/themes/medyasefnewtheme/img/companylogo.png",
            "category_title"    => "Bu Başlık",
            "category_excerpt"  => $pushMessage,
            "category_content"  => $pushMessage,
            "category_date"     => "$today",
            "category_number"   => "5"
        );
        $pushStatus = sendPushNotificationToGCM($gcmRegIds, $message);
    }
}
```

This is my error

```
03-26 11:48:49.591  29416-29495/com.medyasef.bulenttirasmobileapp.bulenttirascom E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GcmNotificationService]
    Process: com.medyasef.bulenttirasmobileapp.bulenttirascom, PID: 29416
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.medyasef.bulenttirasmobileapp.bulenttirascom.GCM.GcmNotificationService.onHandleIntent(GcmNotificationService.java:50)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

This is GcmNotificationService.java:50

```
Log.d( "get_content", get_category_content );
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Which line is 50 in the code?

Comment: Android supports internationalisation (i18n) so Turkish won't be a problem. Like Szymon said, please post your codes from line 45 to 60 so we can see what you're trying to do, and why you get the error on line 50.

Comment: I edit my question 50 in code Log.d( "get_content", get_category_content );
so String get_category_content  = get_extras.getString( DatabaseControl.POSTS_CONTENT ); nullpointerexception